# Create multiple unique states using vuex-persistedstate in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am learning vue.js and trying to use [vuex-persistedstate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate) to save some states. I created a simple todo app and each one has a unique id.

I am iterating through all of them and create a vue instance like this:

```
<div id="todo-list-1" class="todo-list">...</div>
<div id="todo-list-2" class="todo-list">...</div>
<div id="todo-list-3" class="todo-list">...</div>
```

```
document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list').forEach(list => {
   new Vue({
     el: `#${list.id}`,
     render: h => h(App)
   })
})
```

I want to create a state when all todo items in each todo list are completed, for example one for `todo-list-1` and one for `todo-list-2` and so on.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    completed: false
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  mutations: {
    completed: state => state.completed = true,

  }
});
```

How can I create local storage states based on id for each todo list?

Comment: This is likely XY problem. First of all, you don't need multiple Vue app instances, unless you know that you do. As long as there's 1 app and 1 store, everything is straightforward.

Comment: yes, but I need to have multiple vue instances, I want to have different todo lists for different purposes with different data api.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a proper reasoning, more that like you need multiple components, not apps. If you're still learning Vue, it makes sense to start doing it the right way. The right way is to stick to 1 app instance by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option that you have is to create multiple instances of your Vuex store.

Something like

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.todo-list').forEach(list => {
   new Vue({
     el: `#${list.id}`,
     store,
     render: h => h(App)
   })
})
```

You might run into problems trying to manage multiple Vuex stores. See [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/414) for reference.

You might be better served taking a step back and thinking about the structure of your data. You can set up a single Vue instance, and add a boolean to your to-do list item data object.

You could also consider [making localStorage reactive](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-make-localstorage-reactive-in-vue/) if it would help with your implementation.

Comment: do you have any examples how I can use the store when I add it like this?

Comment: I don't have anything handy. What you're trying to do loosely resembles a micro frontend architecture, where there are different sections of the page that are independent, but "stitched" together to create a cohesive page.

https://micro-frontends.org/ might be able to give you some direction. I've seen organizations use Docker to build a container that assembles the different pages. I'll add additional comments if I find anything else.